# Which event is fired when Content property is changed

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

I have two Pages `ProductSearch`,`ProductDetail` and Im changing the `Content` property to Navigate between Pages. I want to know if any events are fired so I can write some code in it?

On `ProductDetail` Page I have `UIElement` property

```
public UIElement MainContent { get; set; }
```

On `ProductSearch` Page I Navigate to `ProductDetail` By setting the `Content` property like this:

```
 private void OnGetDetailsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    ProductDetail productDetail = new ProductDetail();
    productDetail.MainContent = this.Content;
    this.Content = productDetail;
 }
```

On `ProductDetail` Page's `Back` Button I navigate back to `ProductSearch`:

```
private void OnBackButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.Content = MainContent;
}
```

Now I want to know how can I call a method when I navigate Back to `ProductSearch` Page i.e how would I know  that I have Navigated from `ProductDetail` Page? I tried to check if it loads the page but found out that When you change content of control it doesn't fire the `load` event of the page. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yea this will not execute the load event since your are only changing the content obviously.

if you want to take advantage of navigation you should check out this video. Even if its done with blend the concepts apply also with Visual STudio: https://vimeo.com/6599527 (Simple Silverlight Master/Detail Navigation App with Blend 3)

You should check out articles on master detail binding like this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645060(v=vs.95).aspx

The key is to take advantage of the powerful binding concepts which come with silverlight. And if you are not using deep linking you might want to consider using a user control to hide/show details instead of a extra page.

HTH

Comment: So no event is fired when we Navigate like this? Neither any property is changed? Or is there any trick that I can use to get notified when I Navigate Back to the Page?

Comment: Not that I am aware off. Are you using the silverlight Navigaton controls which allows you to hook in? These are the available events: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Otherwise you can drag an ContentControl on the silverlight page. And attach MainContent to the DataContext. Then you can subscribe to DataContextChangedEvent